# Text under PNG display using Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, tkinter, png

I am working on tkinter and what I wanted to do was to show a cancel sign (a PNG) over text that will show the price in background of PNG.

So far I was able to display the text over the image properly using the "compound" option of tkinter.label(). 
But I have tried different ways to get the PNG on top of text but i haven't succeeded so far.

Is what I am trying to do at all possible? If yes kindly guide, if no, then suggest me a way around. what is the closest I can make using the available features.
I even tried making a cancel sign using canvas.draw() but that also hides the text.

Kindly help me out

Regards

Comment: @abccd PNG also has the transparent part. that should show whatever is behind it. in my case when i use the png, it covers the whole area of the image. I can change the background color of that transparent part but not able to make it show the text behind. Hope i explained it better this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best solution to display a partially transparent PNG on top of a text in tkinter is probably to use a `Canvas` with the `create_text()` and `create_image()` methods.

Example code (**Python 2.x**):

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
from urllib import urlopen

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_text(150, 150, text="word word word word word word word word")
url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/etqan5h62d14mv8/Pikachu-PNG-Photos.png?dl=1"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=BytesIO(urlopen(url).read()))
canvas.create_image(150, 150, image=img)

root.mainloop()
```

For **Python 3.x**, use the following in the import statements:

```
import tkinter as tk
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

You should get this:

[image]